# Chart js background color changes on click

Tags: javascript, angular5, chart.js

I have stacked bar in built with chart js. The bar has three rows with the top row background set as white like below.

[image]

The above works fine and this is how i set

```
this.barChart.datasets = [
    {
        label: myLabels1,
        data: myData1,
        dataLabel: ['', ''],
        backgroundColor: ['#FFC500', '#673AB6']
    },
    {
        label: totalLabels,
        data: totalData,
        backgroundColor: ['#FFFFFF', '#FFFFFF']
    }
];
```

The above works fine as i want it to . The problem occur when i click on the bar . It adds a background color on top of the existing color like below. The bgColor appear like a shadow below because the top row is white hence the shadow.

[image]

I have tried everything possible to disable this change all to no avail. I tried playing with the click event of the chart yet nothing works. Please how do i disable such effect? From where does it come from ? Any help would be appreciated.

Chart.js version

`"chart.js": "^2.6.0",`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, That is not chart.js adding a background color to your component but rather your browser displaying that you have this area under selection. I don't think this can be resolved unless you disable selection of the chart by adding this CSS to it.

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't seem to disable the select . I copied the above to mycomponent.scss .

Comment: I looked through the API docs and it looks like there is no direct way of applying additional CSS to the bars of a chart. Since CSS flows down HTML heirarchy you can add the class to a parent div that holds the entire chart. This will have the downside of making your chart unselectable, however.